# WPF: Which is the exact SystemColor for a TextBox BorderBrush property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, textbox

I'm looking for the exact default border color for a TextBox element because I need to assign it to a Brush property.

`My_BorderBrush = SystemColors. ??? ;`

I already tried:

`My_BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush;`

and some others but I can't find the exact one. Every color is slightly different from the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
```

The templates used to define wpf controls look do not always use system brushes.

If you select a textbox in the designer, right click and choose Edit Template to create a template you can see the whole thing:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```